# Как правильно компоновать объекты с прозрачностью?

Tags: opengl, opengles

Решил в своей 2d игре добавить глубину, чтобы можно было задавать на каком плане должны рисоваться объекты и столкнулся с такой проблемой: как подобрать корректную `glBlendFunc`. Для текстурирования я использую `png`, так что изначально использовал функцию такого вида:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Насколько я могу судить эта функция использует `alpha` для смешивания, которых у меня может быть только 2 значения: 0 (для `transparency`) и 1 (если есть хоть что-нибудь). Когда мы смешиваем цвет фона, к примеру `0,1,0,1` и `transparency`, то получаем цвет фона (зеленый) с `alpha` = 1 - и в этом проблема. Так как потом у нас может рисоваться объект на заднем плане, и он уже будет виден, так как `transparency` с ее `alpha` = 0 была заменена на зеленый цвет, с `alpha` = 1. Я вижу выход в том, чтобы при смешивании, для конечного цвета выбиралась меньшая `alpha`, но немогу понять, как это записать в `glBlendFunc`.

Comment: Лично мне по вашему объяснению ничего не понятно. Можете привести пример, а лучше несколько? Пара цветов (RGBA): которым рисуете, и поверх которого рисуете. И результат, который хотите получить после смешивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все делается немного иначе. Главный секрет в том, чтобы сначала отсортировать объекты по расстоянию от камеры, и, потом, рисовать сначала все непрозрачные, а потом полупрозрачные:

1. Все объекты с бинарной (0/1) или отсутствующей прозрачностью рисуются от ближнего к дальнему с использование Z буфера и отсечением прозрачных частей (чтобы эти части в Z ничего не писали). `glBlendFunc` тут любой. Включите discard в шейдере (`if(color.a <= 0.5) discard;`).
2. Все объекты с полупрозрачными частями рисуются от дальнего к ближнему, с Z тестом (чтобы более ближние непрозрачные их перекрывали)и, как раз, с `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`.

Comment: Если объекты отсортированы, то почему бы не рисовать их сразу все вместе, с выключенным z-buffer'ом, от дальнего к ближнему?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это делается для уменьшения нагрузки на GPU. Непрозрачным объектам все равно в каком порядке они рисуются, но если мы рисуем спереди-назад, то каждый пиксель заполняем максимум один раз, для ближайшего объекта (а все остальные разы сработает Z-test). Если же мы пойдем наоборот, сзаду-наперед (без Z-test), то пиксель может перерисовываться несколько раз, зазря.

Comment: По поводу первой части: еще до вашего ответа я нашел решение, такое же - не рисовать значения с alfa 0, но другим способ, не прямо из шейдера. В gl есть glAlphaFunc, которой я задал соответствующее значение и все заработало.

Comment: Хотя теперь смотрю: они не поддерживаются es - попробую ваш способ